# probability that the sum of output of permutation minus input of permutation is even

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

let $\sigma \in S_n$ be an arbitrary permutation from [n] to [n] (an uniform probability).

we will now choose $j \in [n] $ and the question is :

whats the probability that 
$\sum_{i=0 , \ i\neq j}^{n}{|\sigma(i)-i|}$ is even ?

---

i recomend to use the fact that for any permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ from [n] to [n] $\sum_{i=0}^{n}|\sigma(i) - i|$ is even!